# JSON file input error on fs module of nodejs websocket script

Tags: json, node.js, socket.io, fs, pm2

I have a json file which is updated every 30 seconds by an application on the server.  I have written a small server script for nodejs to provide this json file over websocket (socket.io) as given below.

```
var app = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(8081, '127.0.0.1');

io.on('connection', function(socket) { 
  fs.readFile('/tmp/live-info', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    firstDataObj = JSON.parse(data);
    socket.emit('alert', firstDataObj );
  });
});

var prObj;

setInterval(function(){    
  fs.readFile('/tmp/live-info', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    scTime = data.schedulerTime;
    delete data.schedulerTime;
    if (JSON.stringify(prObj) !== JSON.stringify(data)) {
      prObj = data;
      console.log(prObj.current.name, io.engine.clientsCount);
      prObj.schedulerTime = scTime;
      io.emit('alert', prObj );
      delete prObj.schedulerTime;
    } else {
    console.log("No change", prObj.current.name, "Total connections: ", io.engine.clientsCount);
    }
  });
}, 21100);
```

As you can see, the script periodically checks for changes to the json file and will emit the parsed object if changes in contents (except the timestamp) are detected.

I am managing nodejs process on the server using pm2.  Everything works fine but I am repeatedly getting the follow error on the logs

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
   at Object.parse (native)
   at /var/www/scheduleio/server.js:15:25
   at tryToString (fs.js:449:3)
   at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:436:12)
```

There are no noticeable breaks found on the client as well.  However, I would like to understand how to fix this error as I am getting around 200 of them on the logs each day and if the script can be enhanced in any way (as this is my first such script).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the error comes when the file is being written by the other application while your nodejs script is checking it therefore parsing the JSON while it's not completely written.

The error `unexpected end of JSON input` means the JSON is malformed.